# Difference in hugepage value between /etc/default/grub and /proc/meminfo

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2

I am seeing difference in huge page values between the /etc/default/grub file and /proc/meminfo. I have got 107520 in /etc/default/grub file. But /proc/meminfo shows 106856. What can be the reason?

```
root@node:~# cat /proc/meminfo  | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:    356352 kB
HugePages_Total:   106856
HugePages_Free:    106856
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB

root@node:~# cat /etc/default/grub | grep GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=" console=tty0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 rootdelay=90 nomodeset hugepagesz=2M hugepages=107520 isolcpus=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47, root=UUID=f1607a89-1aaa-4766-8e66-936e3a44e223 "

root@node:~# cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.13.0-85-generic root=/dev/mapper/os-root ro console=tty0 net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 rootdelay=90 nomodeset hugepagesz=2M hugepages=107520 isolcpus=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47, root=UUID=f1607a89-1aaa-4766-8e66-936e3a44e223 nomdmonddf nomdmonisw crashkernel=384M-:128M
```

Comment: rather than grepping through  `/etc/default/grub` it's easier to use `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, added /proc/cmdline contents...

Comment: @karthikeeyan You didn't need to add the line, I was just trying to save you some typing in the future :)

Comment: did you set it in `/etc/default/grub` yourself?

Comment: no, i didn't.. it is setting through some automation tool, there are no math calculations here, static value is pushed to config file